# C# Client to server. Get server response?

Tags: c#, cmd, server, client

I am having trouble reading the response of the server after it has been read before. I can get the response of the server the first time it has been read but when I send something else back to the server the response will be `null`  and I get a crash on the `response = sr.ReadToEnd();`.

What should happen with the two `args` is it updates the location with the second `arg`. Then it sends to the server and then the server responds with *Ok*. In following requests the new location is used instead of the first one.

The [error message](https://ibb.co/hgNKrF) complains abouut line 102, which is:

```
response = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

This is the first writing of the `args` to the server and the response being given.

```
// these are the args being sent to the server
sw.WriteLine(args[0]);

// the flush sends this to the server which the response is then read
sw.Flush();

try
{
    response = sr.ReadToEnd();

    //[some if statement...]

    else if (args.Length == 2)
    {
        //response = sr.ReadLine();
        if (args[1] != response)
        {
            // this is what should be put in 'sw.write()' for the updated database entry
            // <name><space><location><CR><LF>
            // cssbct +  " " + "is in fenner", so "cssbct location has changed"
            // args[0] + " " + response
             
            // response is now what the arg is
                response = args[1];

            // write the new response so that it will be sent to the server
            sw.WriteLine(args[0] + " " + response);

            // send it to the server
            sw.Flush();

            // write out the args and that the location has changed
            Console.WriteLine(args[0] + " " + " location changed to be" + " " + response);

            // just testing what the response should be 
            Console.WriteLine(args[0] + " " + response);
               
            // read the response from the server
            response = sr.ReadToEnd();

            // if it equals "OK" do this
            if (response == "OK")
            {
                // drops connection to the server
                // probably not what is needed but look at later date
                Console.WriteLine(response);
                Console.WriteLine("Client connection closed");

                client.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    sw.Flush();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Is what I am doing the correct way to receive the second response by the server?
I dont find a way using the `streamReader/Writer` to get the second response of the server.

**EDIT: The connections**

```
string response = "";
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

client.Connect("whois.net.dcs.hull.ac.uk", 43);

// client.Connect("whois.networksolutions.com", 43);
Stream stream = client.GetStream();

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
```

Spec of the Client and server response

1. A request from Client to server Using 1 Arg: **name CR LF**
2. A request from client to server Using 2 Args to update the DB:

**name space location CRLF**

Server responses (don't have access to the server code, it is just said it will just do such things)

1. A response from server looks like: 
   [drops connection]
2. If no entries are found

   "ERROR: no entries found
   [drops connection]
3. If the server updates the `database` wit the new location:
   OK
   [drops connection]

An *idea*: Could the reason for the response being `null` be that it has reached the end of the stream?

Comment: `ReadToEnd()` reads to the end of anythng that will ever be written to the stream. It doesn't mean "read to an arbitrary point which I haven't shown anywhere." You have to tell the client how much data is coming in, otherwise the read will just wait forever until the end. If it's a simple text based protocol, you could rather use `ReadLine()`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thank you, but even so the crash still happens. Can't understand why.

Comment: Needs more information. For example, how the server does things, how the connections are handled etc.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Have added some more detail.